# Authenticate Django Rest Framework when using Google Auth

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, jwt

When I do JWT authentication through username/password, it works like this:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

'''post looks like: <QueryDict: {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Pd1mjNUXEdeiObEGOg8oNeqU18nwMVkSu8C29e0POGKwa2kY3yHiXk6hOEzuatMg'], 
    'email': ['tom@gmail.com'], 
    'password': ['xyxyzuzu'], 
    'evaluateUsername': ['Login']
}>'''

tokens = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer().validate(request.POST)
request.session["accessToken"] = tokens["access"]
request.session["refreshToken"] = tokens["refresh"]
```

Easy enough. However, if I'm using Google Login, I don't have access to the user's email or password. I can grab the email easily in the following way:

```
if not request.POST.get('email'):
    request.POST._mutable = True
    request.POST['email'] = user.email
    # request.POST['password'] = '********' # placeholder
    request.POST._mutable = False
```

But it will still fail on the django `authenticate(user, password)`, so I get the following error:

> rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: [ErrorDetail(string='No active account found with the given credentials', code='invalid')]

How would I get around this, as I truly don't know the user's password if they're logging in with Google Auth, and any way to provide a falsey value results in an error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the block:

```
if not request.POST.get('email'):
    request.POST._mutable = True
    request.POST['email'] = user.email
    # request.POST['password'] = '********' # placeholder
    request.POST._mutable = False
```

already has the users sessiontoken, so for the unavailable endpoints you could enable the `SesssionAuthenticationMiddleware` in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: I think this has already been done? `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` the issue above is logging the user in via the DRF `validate()` method.

Comment: ah i miunderstood, gonna delete this in a bit

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could figure out how to do this was to overwrite the `validate` method. For example:

```
class TokenObtainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username_field = User.USERNAME_FIELD

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TokenObtainSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """
        Overwrite the `validate` method because with Google Auth we don't have a password.
        """

        email = attrs[self.username_field]
        self.user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        return {}
```

Comment: So just to be clear you're trying to auth someone via their email only right?